# text segmentation based on punctuation marks, especially at clause level

Tags: python, regex, nlp, punctuation, text-segmentation

I want to segment the text when we encounter the punctuation mark in a sentence or paragraph. If I use comma(,) in my regex it is also chunking the individual nouns verbs or adjectives separated by comma.
 Suppose we have "dogs, cats, rats and other animals". Dogs becomes a separate chunk, which I do not want to happen. 
Is there anyway I can ignore that using regex or any other means in nltk where I can only get comma separated clause as a text segment

**Code**

```
from nltk import sent_tokenize
import re
text = "Peter Mattei's 'Love in the Time of Money' is a visually stunning film to watch. Mrs. Mattei offers us a vivid portrait about human relations. This is a movie that seems to be telling us what money, power and success do to people in the different situation we encounter.
text= re.sub("(?<=..Dr|.Mrs|..Mr|..Ms|Prof)[.]","<prd>", text)
txt = re.split(r'\.\s|;|:|\?|\'\s|"\s|!|\s\'|\s\"', text)
print(txt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too complicated to be solved with a regex: there is no way for the regex to know that there is a predicate (verb) within the clause candidate and if you expand it, you would break into another clause.

The problem you are going to solve is called *chunking* in NLP. Traditionally, here were regex-based algorithms based on POS tags (so, you need to do POS tagging first). NLTK has [a tutorial for that](http://www.nltk.org/howto/chunk.html), however, this is a rather outdated approach.

Now, when fast and reliable taggers and parsers are available (e.g., in [Spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features)). I would suggest analyzing the sentence first and then finding chunks in a constituency parse.

Comment: Thanks Jindrich, I explored on to spacy and i have started using spacy for my work. This is much user friendly. Though I haven't been able to address the issue completely, but most of my problem have been solved.